# nd.array to list following a specific list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm beginner in Python ... I have an array (ndarray ) and I want to transform it into a list following another specific list.

I'm working with **python 3**

For example :

```
 ['Notre-Dame de Paris, après la bataille 4 juillet 2019 à 10:52'] is my array

 ['NC', 'P', 'NPP', 'P', 'DET', 'NC', 'ADJ', 'NC', 'N', 'P', 'DET'] is my list
```

this list is obtained from the array , each tuple for each word ( Notre-Dame -> NC , de -> P ....)

Doing so, I got a third list, the specific one and the reference :

```
 ['P', 'N', 'ADJ', 'NC', 'DET', 'NPP', 'V', 'VPP', 'ADV', 'PROREL', 'CLS', 'VINF', 'CC', 'PUNC', 'PRO', 'ET', 'CS', 'CLR', 'CLO', 'VPR', 'ADVWH', 'C', 'VIMP', 'CL', 'VS', 'PROWH', 'ADJWH', 'PREF']
```

It's kind of a dictionary.

I would like to get a list full of 0 or 1 if the sentence(array) contains or not each specific tuple(list) following the order

In my example, it would get :

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

because there is a 'P' tuple in my sentence -> 1
                   'N' ...
    .     .
                    .                         -> 1  ..... but 
     there isn't a 'V' tuple                  -> 0  etc..

I tried the hard way with classic function with many if and add 0 or 1 to my result list but I guess there is a easier way in python with some "for ..  in "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminologies are not all correct but that's okay because you're still learning!

If I read the problem correctly, it seems to me that you're comparing each element in an input list, L1, against another list, L2, and outputting a list of boolean values (represented by 1,0) indicating whether each element in L1 exists in L2.

A simple way to go about this, though may not be the most efficient would be:

```
def simple_alg(L1: list, L2: list) -> list:
    output = []
    for element in L1:
        if element in L2:
            output.append(1)
        else:
            output.append(0)
    return output
```

Using list comprehension:

```
def one_liner(L1, L2):
    return [int(e in L2) for e in L1 ]
```

Comment: thanks ! I solved it since, but your answer works well too